# C++ Header and Declaration Nested struct and class syntax

Tags: c++, class, oop, struct

So I'm trying to define a header file and declaration file with the appropriate code. In my class I am using a struct and then using the structs members to initialize other functions. I am not sure how to do the pathing to link the class and struct to the appropriate function and was hoping someone could help.
This is my header file here.

```
class AVL {
public:
    struct node {
        int data;
        node* left;
        node* right;
        int height;
    };
    node* root;
    node* insert(int key, node* tree);
    node* oneright(node*& tree);
    node* oneleft(node*& tree);
    node* twoleft(node*& tree);
    node* tworight(node*& tree);
    int height(node* tree);
    int getBalance(node* tree);
    int preorder(node* tree);
    AVL();
    node* insert(int key);
    void parsetree();
    vector<int> vvector;
    vector<int> hvector;
    vector<int> bfvector;
};
```

The main problem I am having is how to declare it in the .cpp file 
here 
For example, if I wanted to do insert function how would I properly do the syntax. For that I have

```
node* AVL::node::insert(int key, node* tree)
```

But that is throwing me an error and I haven't been able to find anything when searching for it. Thank you!

Comment: You need to fully qualify `node` as return type in the implementation:: `AVL::node* AVL::node::insert(int key, node* tree)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just that `insert` is not a member of node in the code presented...

Comment: To improve your Stack Overflow experience I strongly recommend adding the full text of any error messages you want assistance with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AVL.h

```
    class AVL {
    node* root;
    node* insert(int key, node* root);
    node* insert(int key);
};
```

in AVL.cpp

```
AVL::node* AVL::insert(int key, AVL::node* root) {
    //code here...
}

AVL::node* AVL::insert(int key) {
//code here...
}
```

As it is mention in one the comments, the insert is not a member of the node struct.